# Meu middleware em node não esta funcionado

Tags: node.js, typescript, express.js

```
import express, { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { router } from "../router";
import cors from 'cors';

export class App{
    public server: express.Application;
  
    constructor(){
      this.server = express();
      this.middleware();
      this.router();
      // Tem que ficar sempre por ultimo
      this.errprHandler();
    }

    private middleware(){
      this.server.use(cors())
      this.server.use(express.json());
      
    }
  
    private router(){
      this.server.use(router);
    }

    private errprHandler(){
      this.server.use((err:Error, req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) => {
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
      });
    }
  }
```

Chamo essa class em um arquivo index e dou  `new App().server.listen(3000, () => console.log('localhost:3000'));`

Quero que todo erro da aplicação caia nesse middleware

Comment: Algo assim `app.all('*', (req, res) => {res.status(404).send('<h1>404! Page not found</h1>');}); `

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que a estrutura do seu projeto esta mal feita.  Um middleware deve ser uma função e não uma classe.

**exemplo de um middleware:**

```
export const TestMiddleware = (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
) => {
  if (middlewareComValorSucesso) {
    next(); // chamando next continua a requisição 
  } else {
    console.log(`Acesso Negado!!`);
    res.status(401).send({
      error: "Acesso Negado!!",
    });
  }
};
```

**como utilizar:**

```
router.get(
  "/usuario/:id", // <- rota da requisição
  TestMiddleware,  // <- seu middleware aqui *********!!!!!!!
  MiddlewareTest22,  // <- pode ter varios middleware 
  (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const { id }: {id: number} = req.params;
    // resto de codigo
  }
);
```

Recomendo ler mais sobre express!!